# Kotlin : OnDataChange running twice

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Things are showing up in the recycler view twice. From what I've seen it may be because of my other functions, but I'm not sure how to put them all together to get the desired output. I only want one Fred and one Jerry, but it's giving me two of each. Please help, thank you.

Here is the Logcat:

```
2020-10-15 19:09:23.692 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY BEFORE SORT: [2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.693 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY AFTER SORT: [2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.712 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY BEFORE SORT: [2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt, 2020-10-12 20:06:26:539000-MJTPxt459r1Bq46mCZu]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.730 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY AFTER SORT: [2020-10-12 20:06:26:539000-MJTPxt459r1Bq46mCZu, 2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.734 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-12 20:06:26:539000-MJTPxt459r1Bq46mCZu
2020-10-15 19:09:23.735 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt
2020-10-15 19:09:23.735 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/USER ARRAY: [bYKpBgZKfVgizckl3j3olapL5n33, 5l5iy4Tg0zfp7DyqMtvBphEsmnh1]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.763 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-12 20:06:26:539000-MJTPxt459r1Bq46mCZu
2020-10-15 19:09:23.763 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-11 21:17:40:966000-MJOWfVEeJmHYvVr3Hvt
2020-10-15 19:09:23.763 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/USER ARRAY: [bYKpBgZKfVgizckl3j3olapL5n33, 5l5iy4Tg0zfp7DyqMtvBphEsmnh1]
2020-10-15 19:09:23.769 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Fred
2020-10-15 19:09:23.769 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Jerry
2020-10-15 19:09:23.811 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Fred
2020-10-15 19:09:23.813 7038-7038/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Jerry
```

Here is a bit from my Fragment:

```
    val latestMsgId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
    latestMsgId.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val user = p0.child(firebaseUser!!.uid).getValue(Users::class.java)
                latestMsgId.child(firebaseUser!!.uid).child("lastMsg").setValue(userArray)
            val sortedUsers = user?.getLastMsg()
            for (item in sortedUsers!!) {
                val uidVal = p0.child(item).getValue(Users::class.java)
                uidArray.add(uidVal!!)
                Log.d("UID VAL", uidVal.getUserName().toString())
            }
            userAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Are you unregistering the listener when the fragment is destroyed?

Comment: @m0skit0 I don't think so, how would I go about that?

Comment: With removeEventListener. I also would suggest you keep your data logic separate from the UI elements. The responsibility of a Fragment is drawing the UI, not fetching data from Firebase.

Comment: @m0skit0 thank you, I'll give it a shot and make some adjustments.

Comment: @MrSchurig why not just put a debug point on `OnDataChange` and figure out what is the issue